# How do I scale xtick values axis in pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Given the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y=np.linspace(0,135000, 135001)
t=range(-len(y),0)

plt.plot(t,y)
```

[image]
How can I subsequently scale format or replace the xtick values so that they read -140, -130, -120, 110... 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter` ([see docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter)):

```
plt.gca().get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x/1000), ',')))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I had been looking at the wrong function (ScalarFormatter) in the setter and was going round in circles.